# Why does the stylesheet not render in subpages?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

When I go to **/page1** I can see my stylesheet working but when I go to **/page1/page2** I loose my stylesheet.  I have gone to the webapp2 website and looked at the routing specifications but cant seem to make sense of it.

**Folder Structure**

/main.py
/index.html
/css/style.css
/templates/page1.html
/templates/page2.html

**main.py**

```
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(dir),
                                       autoescape=True,
                                       extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.write(template.render())

class Page1(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/page1.html')
    self.response.write(template.render())

class Page2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/page2.html')
    self.response.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
  [('/', HomePage),
   ('/page1', Page1),
   ('/page1/page2', Page2)
  ], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block section %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block section %}
  <p>Page 1</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**page2.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block section %}
  <p>Page 2</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using relative URL's for your css , which means on pages like `page1/page2` the browser will try and fetch your css from `/page1/css/style.css`

Change your css link to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" media="all">
```

or set base href to /